# Mysql selecting user friendes likes

Tags: mysql

i have these tables

posts table

```
CREATE TABLE `users_posts` (
    `pid` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, /*post id*/
    `uid` INT(11) NOT NULL, /*user who created the post, owner*/
    `created_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `updated_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `post_status` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    `content` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`pid`),
)
```

connections table

```
CREATE TABLE `users_connections` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_1_uid` INT(11) NOT NULL, /*user id*/
    `user_2_uid` INT(11) NOT NULL, /*friend user id of user id*/
    `connections_status` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

likes table

```
CREATE TABLE `post_ups` (
    `upid` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `uid` INT(11) NOT NULL, /*user id who like the post*/
    `puid` INT(11) NOT NULL, /*post owner user id=users_posts.uid*/
    `pid` INT(11) NOT NULL, /*post id=users_posts.pid*/
    `up_status` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`upid`),
    INDEX `uid` (`uid`),
    INDEX `up_status` (`up_status`),
    INDEX `pid` (`pid`)
)
```

i need to select all posts and inside the query i need to check if some of my friend has like the post i'm currently selecting and if true , i can show this post on top of other post to show more relevant content

```
SELECT *,IF(CHECK IF FREIND LIKED  THIS POST PUID == F_UID) FROM users_posts
```

is this possible ??

Comment: Which post you are selecting, and on which behalf

Comment: posts fome users_posts (SELECT * FROM users_posts )

Comment: How is a friend liking the post? in form of your table data...

Comment: Please write colums' descriptions which is user_id, which is friends user_id, which is post_id etc.

Comment: i edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query must like below:

```
SELECT up.*, 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM post_ups pups 
      WHERE up.pid=pups.pid AND  up.uid <> pups.uid/*exclude own like*/
        AND EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM users_connections uc 
                            WHERE uc.user_1_uid=up.uid/*pups.puid*/ AND uc.user_2_uid=pups.uid)) relevance
  FROM users_posts up
ORDER BY relevance DESC;
```

Comment: i need the result to be inside the query i don't want to select posts the friends has liked , i need to select all posts and inside the query i need to check if some of my friend has like the post i'm currently selecting and if true ,  i can show this post on top of other post to show more relevant content